# How to restore Wallets using Mnemonic Phrases in ethersjs with compatibility to MyCrypto?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js

﻿﻿I'm curious how I can be compatible with **MyCrypto** in terms of Recovery Phrases using `ethers.js`.

Lets say, I have the following Mnemonic:

`federal train gather tumble service amount address need tail crunch better baby`

which leads to a public address:  `0xd4E22d1ffe328d8b3F834fa5791f50C16E453a0d`

Code:

```
const derivationPath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0";
var hdNode = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
var childNode = hdNode.derivePath(derivationPath + '/' + index);

var w = new ethers.Wallet(childNode.privateKey);
console.log(w.address);
```

Importing this passphrase into **MyCrypto** will also return the same address, but NOT anymore once I have added a password.

Let's import this wallet into **MyCrypto** like this:

**Mnemonic Phrase:** `federal train gather tumble service amount address need tail crunch better baby`
**Password**: "test"

The first generated address will be `0x3454Bd153214d900253812b4D47787eF23cD76e6` and not that one mentioned above any more. Only when I remove the password and leave it empty, the same wallet-address will be generated.

How can we produce the same thing with ethersjs?

Adding a 13th word to the mnemonics is will give error message "invalid mnemonic".

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum has legacy and modern BIP39 derivation paths. Unfortunately wallets sometimes use incompatible derivation paths.

Here are some common paths:

- Ethereum — m’/44’/60’/0’/0
- Ethereum Classic — m’/44’/61’/0’/0
- Ethereum Testnet (Ropsten) — m’/44’/1’/0’/0
- Ethereum (Ledger) — m’/44’/60’/0’
- Ethereum Classic (Ledger) — m’/44’/60’/160720’/0
- Ethereum Classic (Ledger, Vintage MEW) — m’/44’/60’/160720’/0’
- Ethereum (Ledger Live) — m’/44’/60’
- Ethereum Classic (Ledger Live) — m’/44’/61’
- Ethereum (KeepKey) — m’/44’/60’
- Ethereum Classic (KeepKey) — m’/44’/61’

[See the source blog post for derivation paths.](https://medium.com/myetherwallet/hd-wallets-and-derivation-paths-explained-865a643c7bf2). For the authoritative source, please read the wallet source code and pick the derivation path from there.